# Is atoi() part of C standard?

Tags: c, type-conversion, atoi

Is `atoi()` part of C standard?

What should I use to convert `char*` to `int` if `atoi()` isn't standardised?

Comment: `atoi` is standard, but `itoa` is not.

Comment: You could ask the same question for hundreds of different functions ... or you could look it up. e.g., googling atoi yields http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/atoi.3.html which says "CONFORMING TO SVr4, POSIX.1-2001, 4.3BSD, C99. C89 and POSIX.1-1996 include the functions atoi() and atol() only".

Comment: @JimBalter: One can also check [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the link is to the latest draft, N1570).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `atoi()` is part of standard C -- unfortunately.

I say "unfortunately" because it does no error checking; if it returns 0, you can't tell whether it's because you passed it `"0"` or because you passed it `"hello, world\n"` (which <strike>has</strike> may have undefined behavior, but typically returns 0).

The `strtol()` function is more complicated to use, but it does proper error checking. It returns a `long` result, which you can then convert to `int` -- ideally after checking that it's in the range `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`.

Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.22.1.2.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `atoi` has *undefined behavior* when the input is not of the expected form or when it overflows. I'm confused as to why the committee didn't at least make it "safe" in the sense of "returns an unspecified value" so that the interface would be partly usable, but in short, `atoi` is unusable as specified.

Comment: @R..: IMHO it's not just undefined, it *poorly* defined. The standard says "Except for the behavior on error, they is equivalent to
... `(int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)` -- but the description of `strtol` doesn't say what constitutes an "error".

Comment: @R..: A reasonable assumption, but it implies that `atoi("hello")` is well defined and returns 0. BTW, I found an explicit statement in N1370 7.22.1p1 applying to all the `atoi*()` functions: "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the
behavior is undefined."

Comment: Yes. I think the idea is that `atoi` is expected (or at least allowed) to be implemented as a loop that just multiplies by 10 and adds the newly-read digit. Since signed overflow is undefined behavior, `atoi` inherits that undefined behavior.

Comment: In my previous comment (posted 3 years ago today!), "N1370" should be "[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)".

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the [C Standard Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), and should be declared within `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is standard. From `man atoi`:

> NAME
>        atoi, atoi_l -- convert ASCII string to integer
>
> LIBRARY
>        Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

`#include <stdlib.h>`

However, it also says:

> The atoi() function has been deprecated by strtol() and should not be
>   used in new code.

Comment: The `atoi` function has not been deprecated by anyone who has the authority to do so. And the fact that a man page says it's implemented in `libc` doesn't imply that it's standard -- though as it happens it is (and `atoi_l` isn't).

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` is part of the current C standard but consider `strtol` which is also part of the standard and has a more robust interface.